# Haskell module not compiling

Tags: haskell, module

So imagine if i have this module declaration

```
module MyModule
(FavoriteList
,empty
,insert
,delete
)where
  data FavoriteList a = L [a]
empty :: FavoriteList a
empty = FavoriteList []
```

For some reason that surpasses my experience in Haskell this does not compile, sometimes it says that the Data constructor is not in scope, and when i move it in the code it says that exists a parse error in input on the empty function.
Any help?

EDIT:

```
)where
  data FavoriteList a = L [a]
  empty :: FavoriteList a
  empty = FavoriteList []
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is poorly formatted and you need to follow whitespace conventions properly, since the Haskell compiler is whitespace aware.  Something like this should work:

```
module MyModule
    ( FavoriteList(..)
    , empty
    ) where

data FavoriteList a = L [a]

empty :: FavoriteList a
empty = L []
```

You should use the form `FavoriteList(..)` to export the type and all of its constructors, and the constructor for `FavoriteList` is `L`, not `FavoriteList`, which is the type name, so you have to construct a value of type `FavoriteList` using the `L` constructor.

All top level declarations must be at the same indentation level, too, so you can't have

```
    data FavoriteList a = L [a]

empty :: FavoriteList a
empty = L []
```

You have to have

```
data FavoriteList a = L [a]

empty :: FavoriteList a
empty = L []
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete aswer about the problems in the code, much appreciated, and thanks for the (..) tip. It worked based on identation you provided.

Comment: Since this answers your question, it's customary to mark it as the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Since `where` is a block herald, all lines after it must be indented the same amount (or explicit `{;}` must be used).